# Updating several objects in array of objects mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have schema like :

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    skills: [{
        _id: false,
        name: String,
        level: Number,
        exp: Number
    }]
});
```

As example document is like :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b0941419703f80a121c44df"
    },
    "skills": [
        {
            "name": "woodcutting",
            "exp": 1110,
            "level": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "smithing",
            "level": 0,
            "exp": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "reading",
            "level": 0,
            "exp": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "writing",
            "level": 0,
            "exp": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

So I just need to update exp and level of woodcutting and smithing in one query, is it possible, if possible, how?
Or will I need to change all array and set(replace) with it value of skills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`arrayFilters`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) from mongodb 3.6

```
db.collection.update(
  { }, 
  { "$set": {
    "skills.$[skill1].exp": "your_value",
    "skills.$[skill2].level": "your_value",
    "skills.$[skill2].exp": "your_value",
    "skills.$[skill1].level": "your_value"
  }},
  { "arrayFilters": [{ "skill1.name": "woodcutting", "skill2.name": "smithing" }] }
)
```